# How do I express huge integer constraints in ortools's CpModel

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

I am using `cp_model` from `ortools`. One problem I have is that I have to scale up floating points that have 6 decimal points, but if I time everything by 1000000, I am starting to get overflows. Also, I cannot multiple by a smaller multiplier, because while it is okay to have lower accuracy than the 6th decimal point, for each individual term I will need to have 6 decimal points.

My model only needs simple linear combinations with boolean variables. `m[i]` is an array of numbers that I scale up by 1000000, but `sum(m)` will cause 64-bit integer to overflow.

```
model = cp_model.CpModel()
x = [model.NewBoolVar('x' + str(i)) for i in range(n)] 
model.Add(sum(x[i]*m[i] for i in range(n))==M)
```

Comment: Not sure if cp is the right tool for this job, why not use a mip solver?

Comment: MIP solvers have a *relative* precision of 1e-4 to 1e-6, and will delete coefficients that are usually smaller than largest coefficients /1e10.  So MIP solvers will not help either. Are you really sure your data is so precise that you justify this scaling ?